# Facebook Graph API: How to get user blocked list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, block

I need to retrieve the list of blocked users from a page of mine

- I created an app in Meta for developers.
- I have all the permissions.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyysB.png)
- I blocked a person on the facebook front
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeNSO.png)
- When I try to retrieve it in the graph API it returns an empty list
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN1u8.png)

How can I recover the blocked list?